# css - shadow on right and left

Tags: css

hi there i am using the following code to get a shadow on the right and left side of a div tag but all four sides of the div are shadowed...

```
.shadow1 {

   border-right:1px solid #8d8d8d;
   border-left:1px solid #8d8d8d;
   -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #000 ;
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #000;

}
```

is there a way to get the shadow appear only on the right and left side of the div... ?? any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yGLT/4/)

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:20px;
    border:1px solid #8d8d8d;

    -weibkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px -5px #000, -5px 0px 10px -5px #000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px -5px #000, -5px 0px 10px -5px #000;
             box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px -5px #000, -5px 0px 10px -5px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work ok :)

```
box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px -4px #000,
            -5px 0px 5px -4px #000;
```

EDIT: Oh, I'm waaay late :p looks like we came to more or less the same conclusion tho.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://css3-drop-shadows.herokuapp.com/app

It provides a css3 generator at the end.

It uses :before and :after